# Importing .XLS file data to mySQL table

Tags: mysql

How do I import data from a XLS file into a mySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PHPMyAdmin, you should be able to save the data as CSV and then import that into MySQL.

Comment: Yep, that the one way. But had to do it dynamically through PHP. And i used phpexcelreader. thats the cool stuff...:)

Comment: To help others out, you should post that as an answer with a link to the project and mark it as the accepted answer.